# disk usage (du) max-depth equivalent option in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm looking for `du max-depth` option in hadoop similar to `du --max-depth=1` command in linux.

Ex:

```
ash@dev:~/usr $ du -h --max-depth=1
4.0K    ./Foredettinghelgen
44K     ./IssueTrackerBlogInterface
1.9M    ./IssueTrackerProduct
4.8M    ./pyexcelerator
52K     ./levenstein
532M    .
```

I'm aware of `$hdfs dfs -du -h -s` options, however was wondering if there is an option for 'max-depth'.

Comment: Try piping after your hdfs dfs -du -h /somepath | —max-depth=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That flag does not exist](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du)

You'll have to parse the output yourself and sum the bytes.

If all you wanted was max depth of one, then you would do `dfs du -s -h /path/*` to run the command for all folders under `/path`

[Twitter HDFS Du](https://github.com/twitter/hdfs-du) might have some code you can use

Comment: Thank you for the comments. max-depth=1 was an example, I need to  traverse 4 level depth for few directories and for others 7 level. As of now, I'm summing bytes manually, but was wondering if I had an option to do it in max-depth way.

Comment: Don't think so. There's the Twitter-du project which makes a visualization of the HDFS usage based on the Fsimage

Answer (score 0):

Building on cricket_007's answer, you can chain globs to produce something similar to what you want, *but* it will count files as part of the glob, so isn't the same in the case where you have a mixture of directories and files. It also doesn't pick up `.dotfiles` but this is usually not an issue on HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h /path/*/*/*/*         # sorta equivalent to du -sh --max-depth=4 /path/
```